# Java Compare Two Lists

Tags: java, list, comparison, hashmap

I have two lists ( not java lists, you can say two columns)

For example

```
**List 1**            **Lists 2**
  milan                 hafil
  dingo                 iga
  iga                   dingo
  elpha                 binga
  hafil                 mike
  meat                  dingo
  milan
  elpha
  meat
  iga                   
  neeta.peeta
```

I'd like a method that returns how many elements are same. For this example it should be
3 and it should return me similar values of both list and different values too.

Should I use hashmap if yes then what method to get my result?

Please help

P.S: It is not a school assignment :) So if you just guide me it will be enough

Comment: Please suggest any data structure the list is not java list or hashmap or any data structure

Comment: Be sure to think about what you should do in exceptional cases. Can lists contain the same value twice? If so, if "dingo" is in both lists twice, does that count as two elements in common or only one?

Comment: Can you modify one of the List?

Comment: how to edit?? Yes each list can contain similar values multiple time

Comment: There should be a **edit** small link right after the question, below the tags.

Comment: <sniff>Smells like a homework assignment.</sniff>

Answer (score 180, accepted):

**EDIT**

Here are two versions. One using `ArrayList` and other using `HashSet`

Compare them and create your **own** version from this, until you get what you need.

This should be enough to cover the:

> *P.S: It is not a school assignment :) So if you just guide me it will be enough*

part of your question.

**continuing with the original answer:**

You may use a `java.util.Collection`  and/or  `java.util.ArrayList` for that.

The [retainAll](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method does the following:

> *Retains only the elements in this collection that are contained in the specified collection*

see this sample:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Repeated {
    public static void main( String  [] args ) {
        Collection listOne = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("milan","dingo", "elpha", "hafil", "meat", "iga", "neeta.peeta"));
        Collection listTwo = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("hafil", "iga", "binga", "mike", "dingo"));

        listOne.retainAll( listTwo );
        System.out.println( listOne );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For the second part ( similar values ) you may use the [removeAll](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method:

> *Removes all of this collection's elements that are also contained in the specified collection.*

This second version gives you also the similar values and handles repeated ( by discarding them).

This time the `Collection` could be a `Set` instead of a `List` ( the difference is, the Set doesn't allow repeated values )

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Repeated {
      public static void main( String  [] args ) {

          Collection<String> listOne = Arrays.asList("milan","iga",
                                                    "dingo","iga",
                                                    "elpha","iga",
                                                    "hafil","iga",
                                                    "meat","iga", 
                                                    "neeta.peeta","iga");

          Collection<String> listTwo = Arrays.asList("hafil",
                                                     "iga",
                                                     "binga", 
                                                     "mike", 
                                                     "dingo","dingo","dingo");

          Collection<String> similar = new HashSet<String>( listOne );
          Collection<String> different = new HashSet<String>();
          different.addAll( listOne );
          different.addAll( listTwo );

          similar.retainAll( listTwo );
          different.removeAll( similar );

          System.out.printf("One:%s%nTwo:%s%nSimilar:%s%nDifferent:%s%n", listOne, listTwo, similar, different);
      }
}
```

Output:

```
$ java Repeated
One:[milan, iga, dingo, iga, elpha, iga, hafil, iga, meat, iga, neeta.peeta, iga]

Two:[hafil, iga, binga, mike, dingo, dingo, dingo]

Similar:[dingo, iga, hafil]

Different:[mike, binga, milan, meat, elpha, neeta.peeta]
```

If it doesn't do exactly what you need, it gives you a good start so you can handle  from here.

Question for the reader: How would you include all the repeated values?

Comment: @Oscar, My exact thought, but I was not sure if we could have modified the contents of `listOne`, but +1 anyways!

Comment: @poygenelubricants what do you mean by *raw types* not generics? Why not?

Comment: Oscar, did you see my updated question? Does it support repeated values?

Comment: @Oscar: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.8 "The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of genericity into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types."

Comment: @agazerboy, just now, I'm updating the question to also include the "similar" values

Comment: @polygenelubricants answer updated to handle duplicates and raw types. BTW, the *..future version of Java...* is never going to happen. ;)

Comment: Hi Oscar, Thanks for your help. I think your first version works well. In your second version, if there are repeated values it skip them and show result as 3 similar values. While iga is 3 times in list one. So the total should be 5 or more for similar values. I hope my point is clear, what do you say?

Comment: So, do you mean that repeated values should appear?  iga is repeated 6 times in the first list, should it show those 6 times? That's easy, just replace `HashSet` with `ArrayList` and you're done. BTW, **I think that with this help can can figure out the rest.**

Comment: With that change ( s/HashSet/ArrayList ) you should get this output: http://pastebin.com/kxTWNeUx

Comment: Oscar, thanks for your help. It is a very gud start for solving BIG PROBLEM :)

Answer (score 44):

You can try [`intersection()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#intersection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) and [`subtract()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#subtract%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) methods from [`CollectionUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/?org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html).

`intersection()` method gives you a collection containing common elements and the `subtract()` method gives you all the uncommon ones.

They should also take care of similar elements

Comment: Should note that this solution requires Apache Ccommons

Answer (score 17):

If you are looking for a handy way to test the equality of two collections, you can use `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection`, which compares two collections regardless of the ordering.

Answer (score 15):

Of all the approaches, I find using `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils#isEqualCollection` is the best approach. Here are the reasons -

- I don't have to declare any additional list/set myself
- I am not mutating the input lists
- It's very efficient. It checks the equality in O(N) complexity.

If it's not possible to have `apache.commons.collections` as a dependency, I would recommend to implement the algorithm it follows to check equality of the list because of it's efficiency.

Answer (score 11):

Are these really [lists](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (ordered, with duplicates), or are they [sets](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (unordered, no duplicates)?

Because if it's the latter, then you can use, say, a [`java.util.HashSet<E>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and do this in expected linear time using the convenient [`retainAll`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)).

```
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(
        "milan", "milan", "iga", "dingo", "milan"
    );
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(
        "hafil", "milan", "dingo", "meat"
    );

    // intersection as set
    Set<String> intersect = new HashSet<String>(list1);
    intersect.retainAll(list2);
    System.out.println(intersect.size()); // prints "2"
    System.out.println(intersect); // prints "[milan, dingo]"

    // intersection/union as list
    List<String> intersectList = new ArrayList<String>();
    intersectList.addAll(list1);
    intersectList.addAll(list2);
    intersectList.retainAll(intersect);
    System.out.println(intersectList);
    // prints "[milan, milan, dingo, milan, milan, dingo]"

    // original lists are structurally unmodified
    System.out.println(list1); // prints "[milan, milan, iga, dingo, milan]"
    System.out.println(list2); // prints "[hafil, milan, dingo, meat]"
```

Comment: well I really don't know which data structure it should be. It has duplicates. Now you can see updated question

Comment: Will it remove the repeated values from data set? coz I don't want to loss any value :(

Comment: @agazerboy: I've tried to address both questions. Feel free to ask for more clarifications.

Comment: thanks poly. I tried your program with duplicates for example in first list i added "iga" two times but still it return me 3 as an answer. While it should be 4 now. coz list 1 has 4 similar values. If i added one entry multiple time it should work. What do you say? Anyother data structure?

Answer (score 7):

Using java 8 removeIf

```
public int getSimilarItems(){
    List<String> one = Arrays.asList("milan", "dingo", "elpha", "hafil", "meat", "iga", "neeta.peeta");
    List<String> two = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("hafil", "iga", "binga", "mike", "dingo")); //Cannot remove directly from array backed collection
    int initial = two.size();

    two.removeIf(one::contains);
    return initial - two.size();
}
```

Comment: It looks good, but if I want to keep the lists unmodified I would have to clone one of the lists and that wouldn't be desired in certain cases.

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution :-

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "d", "c"));
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("b", "f", "c"));

    list.retainAll(list2);
    list2.removeAll(list);
    System.out.println("similiar " + list);
    System.out.println("different " + list2);
```

Output :-

```
similiar [b, c]
different [f]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `hash1` and `hash2`

```
List< String > sames = whatever
List< String > diffs = whatever

int count = 0;
for( String key : hash1.keySet() )
{
   if( hash2.containsKey( key ) ) 
   {
      sames.add( key );
   }
   else
   {
      diffs.add( key );
   }
}

//sames.size() contains the number of similar elements.
```

Comment: He wants the list of identical keys, not how many keys are identical. I think.

Comment: Thanks stefan for your help. Yeah Rosdi is correct and you as well. I need total number of similar values and similar values as well.

Comment: Use libraries, this method is very amateur, look this method:  List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,3,4,5);
                    List<Integer> target = List.of(1,2,3,40,50);
                    List<Integer> result = list.stream().filter(v -> !target.contains(v)).collect(Collectors.toList());

                    // Prints [4, 5] - items in the list not found in the target
                    System.out.println(result);

Answer (score 1):

I found a very basic example of List comparison at [List Compare](http://www.gitarani.com/classified.htm?classifiedId=3012)
This example verifies the size first and then checks the availability of the particular element of one list in another.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean compareList(List ls1, List ls2){
    return ls1.containsAll(ls2) && ls1.size() == ls2.size() ? true :false;
     }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> one = new ArrayList<String>();
    one.add("one");
    one.add("two");
    one.add("six");

    ArrayList<String> two = new ArrayList<String>();
    two.add("one");
    two.add("six");
    two.add("two");

    System.out.println("Output1 :: " + compareList(one, two));

    two.add("ten");

    System.out.println("Output2 :: " + compareList(one, two));
  }
```

Comment: This solution returns the wrong result when two contains 3 copies of "one".  It would incorrectly produce a true result.

Comment: Thanks for this part : && ls1.size() == ls2.size()

Comment: Any reason that you think `? true :false` is needed for in your snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected <T> boolean equals(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
  
        if (list1 == list2) {
            return true;
        }
 
        if (list1 == null || list2 == null || list1.size() != list2.size()) {
            return false;
        }
       // to prevent wrong results on {a,a,a} and {a,b,c} 
       // iterate over list1 and then list2
        return list1.stream()
                .filter(val -> !list2.contains(val))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .isEmpty()  &&
               list2.stream()
                .filter(val -> !list1.contains(val))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .isEmpty();
    }
```