# Comparing elements in arrays

Tags: java

I am stuck on one component of a java assignment for a data structures class that is preventing me from completing the rest of it. It is a simple concept but I am missing something in the implementation. I have a `Dynamic array` called `list1` and I need to compare it to another list (`list2`). I have a method: `equals(Object a)` so the call is `list1.equals(list2);`

I know how to compare lists with an iterator but how do I reference the `list1` Object to compare the two?

I am not asking for you to do my assignment, just help me understand how this would work.

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        DynamicArrayOfInts list1 = new DynamicArrayOfInts();        

    }   
    public DynamicArrayOfInts() 
    {
      storage = new int[INITIAL_CAPACITY]; 
      size = 0;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object aThat) 
    { 
        if(aThat.equals(storage))
            return true;
        else    
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: this is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do something like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if(obj == null) return false;
    if(obj.getClass() != DynamicArrayOfInts.class) return false;

    DynamicArrayOfInts other = (DynamicArrayOfInts) obj;

    /*compare this.storage to other.storage with the iterator
    or with simple indexing.*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was missing. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying that you do the comparison inside the `equals` method.  If that is so, you need to cast the argument `a` to a list.  So

```
public boolean equals(Object a) {
    MyList list1 = (MyList) a; 
    ...
}
```

The line `MyList list1 = (MyList) a` means "treat the reference `a` as a reference to an instance of `MyList`, and assign it to the reference `list1`.

`equals` typically takes an `Object` so you can pass (almost) anything in to `equals`.  Depending on the specific case, the first thing you can do is check the type of the argument to `equals` and return false if it has no chance of being equal.

[Look at this example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) I found on the intertubes.  The first thing you see in their example is

```
if ( this == aThat ) return true;
if ( !(aThat instanceof Car) ) return false;
```

doing things like this allows you to return quickly if the comparison is trivial.  For example, it's a tautology that an instance is equal to itself; there is no way that cannot be true.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the equals method you use the `this` operator to access list1 in place of the nae `list1`.