# Comparing two arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two array lists listA and listB which may or may not contain same elements. 
For Example:

```
listA= [1,2,3] &
listB=[2,3,4]
```

I need to compare the two array lists and add the element which is present in listA and not in listB to listB. Also if any other element which is present in listB is not there in listA, I should delete it from listB.

Please help me how to code for this in Java.

I prefer using Iterator method if needed.

Comment: this sounds a bit like homework? if so it should be tagged as such

Comment: @mfrankli homework tag is depricated

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists

Comment: What's the point? Wouldn't you end up with `listA` as your output?

Comment: is the list index relevant in the comparison?  e.g. if position 0 in list A is 1 and position 2 in list B is 1, does that count as a match or not because of the different position (index)?

Comment: This looks like a merge. Have a look [at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this is the answer =) shortcut.

Comment: @Deepthi I recommend you post your code or what have you done so far and where exactly you are stuck. You may want to read the faq (top right link)

Answer (score 1):

Your description suggests you want to be working with sets. For example, say an element is in A twice but only in B once. Should it be added to B once?

The simplest answer to your question is to

```
List listA = ...
List listB = ...

listB.clear();
listB.addAll(listA);
```

however assuming you want to preserve some order you can do.

```
List listA = ...
List listB = ...
Set setA = new HashSet(listA);
setA.removeAll(listB);

Set setB = new HashSet(listB);
setB.removeAll(listA);

listB.addAll(setA);
listB.removeAll(setB);
```

Note: this will not add entries if A of an element has more than B and it will not remove entries if B has more of an element than A.

Comment: Somehow I think this homework is supposed to demonstrate the use of iterators. I think Sets are taking it a bit too far :)

Comment: @Shark If its homework, I leave it as an exercise for the OP to translate. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(int i : listA)
    if(!listB.contains(i)) listB.add(i);
for(int j : listB)
    if(!listA.contains(j)) listB.remove(j);
```

Otherwise

```
Arrays.sort(listA); Arrays.sort(listB);
for(int i = 0; i < listA.length(); i++)
{
   if(!listB.contains(listA.get(i))) listB.add(listA.get(i));
   if(!listA.contains(listB.get(i))) listB.remove(listA.get(i));
}
```

Comment: What if listB is shorter than listA ?

Comment: I wanted to do "i < Math.min(listA.length, listB.length)" but somehow saw it as overkill as it depends whether the OP thinks we should assume it or the teacher will ask for it.

Comment: I would use `i < listA.length() && i < listB.length()` rather than use `min()`

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps for writing the code

First perform the deletion

```
   Iterate ListB
    For each element in ListB, check if it is present in List A
      If Not, delete from ListB
      else continue
 Close your loops
```

Then Addition

```
Iterate ListA
  For each element in ListA, check if it is present in List B
    If Not, add to ListB
    else continue
Close your loops
```

Sample Code:

```
    List<Integer> listA = ..
    List<Integer> listB = ..

    for(Integer intB: listB)
      if(!listA.contains(intB)){
         listB.remove(intB);
      }
    }   

   for(Integer intA: listA)
      if(!listB.contains(intA)){
         listB.add(intA);
      }
    }
```