# Comparing Java Lists

Tags: java

How can I return `true` if `list1` and `list2` share at least 1 item?

Example: `list1` = (1,2,3) ... `list2` = (2,3,4)

`someFunction(list1, list2); // returns true`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Compare Two Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @chris, what user `loki` below said, but it seemed non-optimal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [`Collections.disjoint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) method.  If it is true there are no items in common.

Comment: +1 Looks like that method attempts to optimize by deciding which collection to iterate and which to check with `contains`, based on a few factors. [\[source\]](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.disjoint%28java.util.Collection%2Cjava.util.Collection%29)

Answer (score 1):

Like TofuBeer said, take a look at [Collections.disjoint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) (I'd upvote his if I had any reputation...):

```
public void main() {
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(2,3,4); 
    someFunction(list1, list2);
}

private boolean someFunction(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {
    return ! Collections.disjoint(list1, list2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over one list using "Iterator" and use contains method of other list to check the element. Isn't it?

Comment: I thought of doing that, but figured there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean someFunction(List<T> l1,List<T> l2)
{
    Iterator<T> i = l1.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        if(l2.contains(i.next())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If space is not an issue, why not just use a HashMap?

```
Iterator it1 = list1.iterator(), it2 = list2.iterator();
Map <K, Integer> listmap = new HashMap <K, Integer> ();

while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
    K elem1 = it1.next(), elem2 = it2.next();
    if ((listmap.get(elem1) != null && listmap.get(elem1) == 2) || 
        (listmap.get(elem2) != null && listmap.get(elem2) == 1)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        listmap.put(elem1, 1);
        listmap.put(elem2, 2);
    }

}
return true
```

This way, you don't have to loop through the entire second array to check each element of the first one, since adding elements to a hash table happens in amortized constant time.

By the way, a faster solution would be to use `IntHashMap` from Apache commons (or `SparseArray` on Android).