# How to Compare two lists in java

Tags: java, list

I have two lists List listOne, List listTwo, and i want to compare both and if both are same i want to add the list item into some other list ol1 else add to ol2.

Here the ElementRangeIndex is a bean class which contains some string values.

While comparing the two lists it needs to compare each string value from the bean.

I have used the below code to but contains adding duplicate values since both lists have different objects.

```
public static Map<Integer, List<ElementRangeIndex>> compareLists(List<ElementRangeIndex> listOne, List<ElementRangeIndex> listTwo) {
     boolean indicator = false;
     List<ElementRangeIndex> listOnes = new ArrayList<ElementRangeIndex>();

     List<ElementRangeIndex> listTwos = new ArrayList<ElementRangeIndex>();
     List<ElementRangeIndex> listThree = new ArrayList<ElementRangeIndex>();

     Map<Integer, List<ElementRangeIndex>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<ElementRangeIndex>>();
    if (listOne!= null && listTwo!=null && listOne.size() == listTwo.size()) {

        for (ElementRangeIndex listTwoData : listTwo) {
            for (ElementRangeIndex listOneData : listOne) {
/* if (listOneData.getNamespaceUri().equals(listTwoData.getNamespaceUri())
                         && listOneData.getCollation().equals(listTwoData.getCollation())
                         && listOneData.getScalarType().equals(listTwoData.getScalarType())
                         && listOneData.getLocalname().equals(listTwoData.getLocalname())) {*/
                if ((listOneData.getNamespaceUri().hashCode()== listTwoData.getNamespaceUri().hashCode())
                        && (listOneData.getCollation().hashCode() == listTwoData.getCollation().hashCode())
                        && (listOneData.getScalarType().hashCode() == listTwoData.getScalarType().hashCode())
                        && (listOneData.getLocalname().hashCode() == listTwoData.getLocalname().hashCode())) {

                    listOnes.add(listOneData);

                    if(listTwos.contains(listOneData))
                        listTwos.remove(listOneData);

                    if(listTwos.contains(listTwoData))
                        listTwos.remove(listTwoData);

                    if(listThree.contains(listOneData))
                        listThree.remove(listOneData);

                    if(listThree.contains(listTwoData))
                        listThree.remove(listTwoData);


                }else{
                        if(!listOnes.contains(listOneData))
                        if(!listTwos.contains(listOneData))
                                listTwos.add(listOneData);
                    if(!listOnes.contains(listTwoData))
                        if(!listThree.contains(listTwoData))
                                listThree.add(listTwoData);

                }

            }
            }
        map.put(1,listOnes);
        map.put(2, listTwos);
        map.put(3, listThree);

        }
    return map;
}
```

My aim is to add similar list items into one list(listOnes), left only to other list(listTwos) and right to other list(listThree).

Thanks,
Arjun

Comment: Use Apache Commons Collections' class `CollectionUtils` which provides methods to extract the elements contained in both collections or in only one. Use a `LinkedHashSet` or something similar to retain insertion order while rejecting duplicates (if you need that).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do the split yourself, I'd probably do something like this:

1. Create a copy of list and name it `leftOnly`. This will contain elements only present in list one.
2. Create a copy of list two and name if `rightOnly`. This will contain elements only present in list two.
3. Create an empty list `intersectList` which will contain elements present in both lists.
4. Up to now `leftOnly` might contain too many elements so we'll need to filter those. To do that we use an iterator to iterate over each element and check whether it is contained in `rightOnly` as well. If it is we remove the element from `leftOnly` and `rightOnly` and add it to `intersectList`.

To speed up that process (`contains` and `remove` on lists are linear operations) you might make `leftOnly` and `rightOny` be of type `LinkedHashSet` which allows for faster operations but would not allow duplicates (using duplicates in the result would break the whole logic anyways).