# Comparing two list of objects in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I am writing JUnit Test case for my java project and using Coverage Tool to check the lines of code are covered. The problem is: I've two list of objects. I need to compare the results of object to be equal using assertTrue or any other possible assert statements. I am getting error like Assertion Error by using below assert statements. Is there any solution to compare two lists easily?

```
//actual    
List<ProjectData> actuals = ProjectManagerDao.getProjects("x", "y", "z");
// expected
List<ProjectData> expecteds = new ArrayList<>();
ProjectData p1 = new ProjectData();
p1.setId("a");
p1.setName("b");
expecteds.add(p1);

assertTrue(JsonProvider.getGson().toJson(actuals).equalsIgnoreCase(JsonProvider.getGson().toJson(expecteds)));
//or
assertTrue(actuals.equalIgnoreCase(expeteds);//Not working for list of objects but working for comparing two strings
```

This differs from [Java Compare Two Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists) in that I need to be able to assert equality in jUnit, not just compare the lists.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I need to compare 2 lists in JUnit assert statements not in Java..

Comment: Just assign the result of the comparison to a `boolean` and then assert on that.

Comment: let me try but Can you show how ??

Comment: You only can compare String with `equalIgnoreCase` but your test needs to compare lists of `ProjectData`. Which part of the ProjectData do you need to compare?

Answer (score 7):

Use [Assert.assertArrayEquals(Object[] expecteds, Object[] actuals)](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29) method to compare two array for content equality:

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected.toArray(), actuals.toArray());
```

`equals` method compares arrays for being the same reference so it's not suitable in test cases.

For your other question: Remember to use org.junit.Assert not junit.Assert which became obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

In short: there is exactly one assert that one needs when writing JUnit tests: **assertThat**

You just write code like

```
assertThat("optional message printed on fails", actualArrayListWhatever, is(expectedArrayListWhatever))
```

where [is()](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#is(T)) is a hamcrest matcher.

This approach does work for all kinds of collections and stuff; and it does the natural "compare element by element" thing (and there are plenty of other hamcrest matcher that one can use for more specific testing; and it is also pretty easy to write your own matchers).

( seriously; I have not seen a single case where assertThat() would not work; or would result in less readable code )

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Assert.assertEquals(java.lang.Object expected, java.lang.Object actual);
```

example:

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("hello");
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add("hello");
Assert.assertEquals(list1, list2);
```

source: [Junit API](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html)

or if you want to use the arrays comparison method you can as below

```
ArrayList<String> list1;
ArrayList<String> list2;

Assert.assertArrayEquals(list1.toArray(), list2.toArray());
```

I would recommend you to use the assertEquals method.

PS: (the user defined objects stored inside the list should have the equals and hashcode methods overridden)

Comment: But Assert.assertEquals shows me deprecated function and 2nd one would work but there is no assert statements like assertArrayEquals

Comment: Ok which version of the JUnit library are toy using ?

Comment: JUnit 4 and also using coverage tool by EclEmma plugin

Comment: ok i get it thats method is deprecated.

Comment: @SRIRAMRAMACHANDRAN have attached the Junit API have a look at it try the Assert.assertEquals(java.lang.Object expected, java.lang.Object actual); method it worked fine for me.

Comment: OP clearly mentions two list of objects. Change your example to `list1.add(new String("hello");` and `list2.add(new String("hello");` and you will know the difference.