# How to check webelements in webtable is sorted alphabetically using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Our application contains table of web elements. My aim is to check whether the contents table is alphabetically ordered.

```
WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();
d.get("http://www.javatpoint.com/wrapper-class-in-java");

WebElement table=d.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='city']/table/tbody"));
List<WebElement> lst=table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
System.out.println(lst);

List ls=new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<=6;i++)
{
    ls=lst.addAll(get(i).getText())
}
```

My aim is to store string type webelement in one list and create another list which is of sorted kind
in the end compare two list. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Compare Two Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can store the default sorting in a string array like `obtainedList` and then sort it using collections for `sortedList` and lastly both.

```
ArrayList<String> obtainedList = new ArrayList<>(); 
List<WebElement> elementList= driver.findElements(By.xpath(YourLocator));
for(webElement we:elementList){
   obtainedList.add(we.getText);
}
ArrayList<String> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();   
for(String s:obtainedList){
sortedList.add(s);
}
Collections.sort(sortedList);
Assert.assertTrue(sortedList.equals(obtainedList));
```

For descending order add:

```
Collections.reverse(sortedList);
```

after `Collections.sort(sortedList);`

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944436/can-ruby-codes-be-converted-to-java-for-webdriver-use

Comment: How about in Selenium with Python, could you support me for this, please. Thank you

Comment: For descending order you have to use Collections.sort(obtainedList,Collections.reverseOrder());

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort(SortedList,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Just improvising  we need to add `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` to match case sensitive sorts!

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean sortVerify() {
    List<WebElement> theList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='productView']/div/div/div/div"));
    List<Integer> Prices=new ArrayList<>();

    for (int NumberOfItem=1; NumberOfItem<theList.size();NumberOfItem++) {
        System.out.println("feteching by xpath price");
        String priceOneRaw=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"p_"+NumberOfItem+"_1\"]/div/div[5]/div/span[1]")).getText();
        System.out.println("feteching by xpath price--------"+priceOneRaw);
        ////below 2 lines are to get the price in exact integers, as earlier it was in format Rs.3829.
    String priceOneFinal=priceOneRaw.replaceAll("[\\-\\?\\+\\.\\^:,\\\u20B9]","");
    String PriceComplete = priceOneFinal.split("Rs")[1];
    int finalPrice=Integer.parseInt(PriceComplete);
    Prices.add(finalPrice);
    }

    int previousPrice=Prices.get(0);
    for(int SortCheckNumber=1;SortCheckNumber<theList.size()-1;SortCheckNumber++) {
        if(Prices.get(SortCheckNumber)<previousPrice) {
            System.out.println("notSorted");
            return false;
        }else {
            previousPrice=Prices.get(SortCheckNumber);
        }

    }
    System.out.println("allSorted");
    return true;
}
```