# Problem with sorting elements Selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, sorting

I have a problem with sorting web elements, sorted elements from the website are in a different order than elements from my sorted-list.

Result:
My sorted String list:

```
[0 0, 1 1, A A, A A, A A, AAAA, AAAA, Cascasc Aaaaa, Jan Jankowski, Jan Janowski, Jan Kon, Jan kowalski, pp]
```

String List from website:

```
[0 0, 1 1, A A, A A, A A, AAAA, AAAA, Cascasc Aaaaa, Jan Jankowski, Jan Janowski, Jan kowalski, Jan Kon, pp]
```

Different order:

```
Jan Kon, Jan kowalski
```

My sorted string list:

```
[0 0, 464 464, A A, A A, a a, a a, a a, a b, a s, aa a, abv sada, ala Janka, ala ola, anna, anna, anna, bankowa]
```

List from website:

```
[0 0, 464 464, a a, a a, a a, a b, a s, aa a, abv sada, ala Janka, ala ola, anna, anna, anna, bankowa, A A, A A]
```

Different order:

```
A A, A A
```

Code:

```
getObtainedList(String css){
    ArrayList<String> obtainedList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    List<WebElement> elementList= driver.findElements(By.CssSelector(css));
     for(webElement we:elementList){
       obtainedList.add(we.getText);
     }
    }
    
    getSortedList(List list){
    ArrayList<String> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();   
     for(String s:list){
     sortedList.add(s);
     }
    }


    List<String> obtainedList = getObtainedList(cssSelector);
    
    List<String> sortedList = getSortedList(obtainedList);
    Collections.sort(sortedList)
    
    Assert.assertEquals(sortedList, obtainedList)
```

Comment: How did you retrieve data from website ? Would you share your code for that ?

Comment: Hi I added code. Code similar to 3th answer from:

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950061/how-to-check-webelements-in-webtable-is-sorted-alphabetically-using-selenium-web)

Comment: if you want them to match, just run the gathered list through your collections.sort method.  Seems like they are doing a toLower or toUpper in their comparator... on the web site.  That might be by design, but seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Hi, I did that too is in the code in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code:

```
ArrayList<String> obtainedList = new ArrayList<>(); 
// Get all options
List<WebElement> elementList= driver.findElements(By.CssSelector(css));

// Creating a list to store drop down options
List options = new ArrayList();


for(WebElement optionElement : elementList)
{
    obtainedList.add(optionElement.getText());
}

  
System.out.println("Options in dropdown with Default order :"+obtainedList);

// Creating a temp list to sort
List tempList = new ArrayList(obtainedList);

Collections.sort(tempList);

System.out.println("Sorted List "+ tempList);

boolean ifSortedAscending = obtainedList.equals(tempList);

if(ifSortedAscending)
{
    System.out.println("List is sorted");
}
else
    System.out.println("List is not sorted.");
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer, @arpita biswas i think we have similar method, I use assert, you use boolean.

Comment: So it means in the website-it is not maintaining a sorted order list. So I think you are able to verify whether the list is sorted or not. So what you are looking for now?

Comment: I thought my sort was bad compared to page sort and I wanted to use e.g. comparator to equals them