# Compare two list common data,new data and old data

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Hi I have two list example List list1 and LIST List list2

How to get common data ?
Data is there in first list only?
Data is there in second list only?

Since i am using List is i need to ovveride equals and hashcode method?

Please could you help with sample example.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Compare Two Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists)

Comment: Do you care about ordering? Are lists [A,B] and [B,A] different? How many differences are there between [B,C] and [A,B,C]? If your answer is 'no' and 'only A' then you are interested in difference between Sets, not lists, which is considerably easier - please rephrase your question in such case.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList onlyInList1 = new ArrayList(list1);
onlyInList1.removeAll(list2);

ArrayList onlyInList2 = new ArrayList(list2)
list2.removeAll(list1);

ArrayList inBoth = new ArrayList(list1)
inBoth.retainAll(list2);
```

Comment: If list1 contains list beans means is i need to override has code and equal method in bean?

Comment: If list1 contains bean1, list2 contains bean2, and bean1 and bean2 do not reference the same object, then yes you should override the "equals()" method.  You should also override "hashcode()" to something reasonable.