# Check if a list contains the same element then get some values on the other list

Tags: java, list

I have two lists with the same objects in them.

```
List<Object1> list1;
List<Object1> list2;

for (Object1 objectItem : list1.getList()) {
    // I want to check if objectItem exists in list2 without using another for loop and then compare their other values
    // Something like list2.getList().contains(objectItem).getThisValueMethod();
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: suppose this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists) has answered this issue and it may be helpful.

Comment: have you implemented `equals` in your custom object?

Comment: What Is `List` instantiated to ? e.g. `ArrayList`?

Comment: @Aominè I have not yet tried implementing `equals` in my custom object.

Comment: @Yahya it is just a `List`, not an `ArrayList`

Comment: @RajithPemabandu thanks! I'll check on this.

Comment: @CronasDeSe in which case you **cannot** utilize `contains` here. you might need to consider implementing that or determine another way to check if _two_ or more objects are _equal_. what condition must be satisfied for two or more objects to be equal in your use case?

Comment: @Aominè only one `String` variable needs must be satisfied for them to be equal. For example, `String name`

Comment: @CronasDeSe "*just a List, not an ArrayList*". `List` is an interface, you must instantiate it to use it!

Comment: @Yahya Oh I'm sorry, yes it is instatiated into an `ArrayList`

Comment: `list1.getList()`? I don't think so...  Why not just `list1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this **Example** (`Explanation in Comments`):

```
// Suppose you have two lists of Objects (Strings in this case)
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

//fill them with some example data
list1.add("1"); list1.add("2"); list1.add("3"); 
list2.add("0"); list2.add("1"); list2.add("2");

// Now you can use ONE for-loop as you asked to check equality
for (String s : list1) {
    if(list2.contains(s)){ // use contains() method which returns true if the Object found
    // indexOf(Object) this method return the index of the given Object in the list
    // get(int index) this return the OBJECT from the list
    // and because Java works by passing reference of object -> you can directly invoke any method
    // that is originally in that Object Class

       list2.get(list2.indexOf(s)); // you can invoke a method on it 
    // because in this case it's a String I can invoke any method from Class String
    // on the the above-object, for example
       list2.get(list2.indexOf(s)).trim(); // this method to remove leading spaces.. and so on

       System.out.println(list2.get(list2.indexOf(s))); // for testing
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I do something like adding a list inside of that list. Is it possible to compare the values inside the inner list when only using one for loop?