# Java: list1=list2 // list1==list2?

Tags: java

what does `list1=list2` and `list1==list2` mean when we use ArrayLists?

```
ArrayList <String> list1, list2;
list1=new ArrayList<>(); list2=new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator and is assigning a reference of `list2` to `list1` and `==` equality operator and checks for referential equality between the two lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Compare Two Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a single equal sign `=` is used to assign values to variables to be used later in your code, this is why it is called the assignment operator.

Two equal signs `==` is a comparative operation between two values which returns a Boolean. For instance `1 == 1` will return `true`, but I would be careful when using this operation with objects and would suggest using the `equals()` or `compare()` method.