# comparing 2 ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

I got 2 ArrayList

List fileArray = new ArrayList();
    List fileTxt = new ArrayList();

```
List<String> newDoc = new ArrayList<String>();        

while((fileName = fileRead.readLine()) !=null){
    fileArray.add(fileName);
}
fileRead.close();

while((txtName = txtRead.readLine()) !=null){
    fileTxt.add(txtName);
}
txtRead.close();
```

I want to compare `fileArray` data with `fileTxt` data, but don't know how to do that, because to I'm thinking to compare I need to get the data first. And to do that I need to looping the array and using the `.get` like

```
for(int a=0;a<fileTxt.size();a++){
    System.out.println(fileTxt.get(a));
}
```

I know this is wrong, but anyone can help me.

note: I want to use something like contains method but can't because the data is 5 million rows. (not equals method)

Updated: I want to find a word in fileTxt that appeared in the fileArray. (so basically its like contains)

Comment: Define "compare", precisely. If you want to test that they are equal, then just use list1.equals(list2). If you want something else, you need to define it first.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to be storing 5M records using an ArrayList

Comment: Are you trying to find the differences between the lines, possibly ignoring whitespace? Compare could mean many things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Compare Two Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists)

Comment: @NicholasK then what should I use for the records?

Answer (score 0):

To compare 2 values in your 2 arraylists, you do this:

```
if(fileArray.get(index).equals(fileTxt.get(index)))
```

Comment: With this method, you need a for loop. And if a list has a value twice, and the second only once, it will succeed with your code, whereas both are different.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wondefull function.

```
System.out.println(array1.equals(array2));
```

Then, you might want to check your answer by hands:

```
    ArrayList like1 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList like2 = new ArrayList(); 
    ...

    boolean flag = true;
    if (!Math.min(like1.size(), like2.size()) == Math.max(like1.size(), like2.size())) 
    {
        flag = false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(like1.size(), like2.size()); i++) {
        if (!like1.get(i).equals(like2.get(i))) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this using the removeAll() method.

```
fileArray.removeAll(fileTxt);
fileTxt.removeAll(fileArray);
```

If one of them still have data, this means that the two List where different.

But storing 5 millions data in a Java list is not something I will advise you. Perhaps you should think about something else.