# Arraylist comparison failing

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to compare an expected list of string values with the actual string values in a list. Below is my code. Though the `expList` and actual list matches,
 boolean is returning false and the assertion throws the error. Please let me know where am I going wrong.

```
public void verifyFilesInFolder(String folder, String... files) {
    navigateToFolder(folder);
    List<String> expList = Arrays.asList(files);
    assertTrue("expected List did not match the actual list ", verifyTheFileNames(locator, expList));
}


public boolean verifyTheFileNames(String locator, List<String> expList) {
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(locator));
    ArrayList<String> actual = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        actual.add(elements.get(i).getText());
    }
    Collections.sort(actual);
    System.out.println("Actual List: " + actual);
    Collections.sort(expList);
    System.out.println("Expected List: " + expList);
    boolean flag = actual.equals(expList);
    if (flag)
        System.out.println("Actual and Expected List are same");
    return flag;

}
```

Output:

> Actual List: [blank.html, blank.jpg, blank.mov, blank.mp3, blank.txt] 
>   Expected List: [blank.html, blank.jpg, blank.mov, blank.mp3,
>   blank.txt]

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: Yes.its failing at boolean flag line of code.

Comment: have you checked your actual, no hidden spaces or anything?

Comment: expList is declared as a List, actualList as an ArrayList. Try setting that to the same

Comment: yes, copied and pasted the actual list values in the expList.But still same issue. Also, tried matching both expList and actual List as ArrayList.It didnt work.

Comment: It's quite strange, you may have a control character in one of the string, try to debug an check the string length of each of them.

Comment: in your for loop, add an : assertTrue (expList.contains(elements.get(i).getText());

Comment: I think the issue is with the files String passing in the method.Am passing it as  String files="blank.html, blank.jpg, blank.mov, blank.mp3, blank.txt". So it is taking as complete string at a time and failing. can some suggest how to handle her.

Comment: split that string by ", "

Comment: converted it to array and it worked.Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Compare Two Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762093/java-compare-two-lists)

Answer (score -1):

Issue resolved by changing the files from String to String[].

Before :

```
String files = "blank.html, blank.jpg, blank.mov, blank.mp3, blank.txt";
```

After :

```
String[] files = {"blank.html", "blank.jpg", "blank.mov", "blank.mp3", "blank.txt"};
```